# typing dropdownlist

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, drop-down-menu, content-type, editing

I want to create a dropdownlist but user can type on it. Then I want to use typed-text to filter data that I already filled dropdownlist with. I want to design it as new control. How can I do?

thank you

Answer (score 2):

You can also look at this.. http://www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/samples/combobox/combobox.aspx

[Update the link above is dead so here is the latest one]
https://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=ComboBox%20Control

Comment: thank you, im talking about  creating new object by modifying dropdownlist object but this is usefull too,

Comment: FYI. The link is dead.

Answer (score 0):

ASP does not have a Editable dropdownlist. There are many available on internet 
have a look at

1. http://authors.aspalliance.com/dotnetsolutions/Article2tmpl.aspx
2. http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/EditableDropdown.aspx

Comment: yes i know asp.net doesn't have editable dropdownlist, i wanna build new dropdown control and i wanna know how can i do it?

Comment: Check the two links in this answer. They have both done it in different ways. I hope it will help.